# Android: Doesn't Allow to use non final variables inside timer

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I wanted to change the image of an Image view using a for loop, a String array and the png images in drawable folder.One Image should rest for 5 seconds then the next should appear.Here is the code I used.And it doesn't allow me to use non final Variables inside the timer.

```
private String [] array1 = {"card2c","card2d","card2h","card2s",
                                    "card3c","card3d","card3h","card3s",
                                    "card4c","card4d","card4h","card4s",
                                    "card5c","card5d","card5h","card5s",
                                    "card6c","card6d","card6h","card6s",
                                    "card7c","card7d","card7h","card7s",
                                    "card8c","card8d","card8h","card8s",
                                    "card9c","card9d","card9h","card9s",
                                    "card10c","card10d","card10h","card10s",
                                    "cardjc","cardjd","cardjh","cardjs",
                                    "cardqc","cardqd","cardqh","cardqs",
                                    "cardkc","cardkd","cardkh","cardks",
                                    "cardac","cardad","cardah","cardas",};

Timer timer = new Timer();
for(int j=0;j<52;j++)
{
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
    //switch image here
    int resID_temp1 = getResources().getIdentifier(array1[j] , "drawable", getPackageName());
    Drawable image_temp1 = getResources().getDrawable(resID_temp1);
    Player1.setImageDrawable(image_temp1);   //Player1 is the ImageView
    }
}, 0, 5000);
```

since variable j and others cannot be final because I change them in every loop..So what can I do..??

Comment: Implement a class that extends TimerTask with a custom constructor

Answer (score 0):

you could make a copy of `j` before you execute like this

```
for(int j=0;j<52;j++)
{
    final int index = j;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //switch image here
        int resID_temp1 = getResources().getIdentifier(array1[index] , "drawable", getPackageName());
        Drawable image_temp1 = getResources().getDrawable(resID_temp1);
        Player1.setImageDrawable(image_temp1);   //Player1 is the ImageView
    }
}, 0, 5000);
```

now you would use `index` instead of `j`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j=0;j<52;j++) {
    final int finalj = j;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //use finalj here
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
}
```

And just to be clear this is not android issue. `An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final` for more information please refer to java specification - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing